# slideToggle from same DIV classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

i am trying implement slidetoggle on class. i have many class but same. it will dynamic so class name same but will be much content. but it not working. i just want when i click **caption** then **captionbox** will open and when i click **close** then **captionbox** will be close.

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li id="arrayorder_42">
            <div class="captionbox">
                <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" placeholder="type your caption"></textarea> <a href="#" class="sbtn_green">save</a>  <a href="#" class="collapsed sbtn_gray">close</a>

            </div>
            <img src="thumbnail/Picture2.jpg" /> <a href="?delete=42" class="sbtn_red">Delete</a>
 <a href="#" class="caption sbtn_gray">caption</a> 
        </li>
        <li id="arrayorder_42">
            <div class="captionbox">
                <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" placeholder="type your caption"></textarea> <a href="#" class="sbtn_green">save</a>  <a href="#" class="collapsed sbtn_gray">close</a>

            </div>
            <img src="thumbnail/Picture2.jpg" /> <a href="?delete=42" class="sbtn_red">Delete</a>  <a href="#" class="caption sbtn_gray">caption</a> 
        </li>
        <li id="arrayorder_42">
            <div class="captionbox">
                <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" placeholder="type your caption"></textarea> <a href="#" class="sbtn_green">save</a>  <a href="#" class="collapsed sbtn_gray">close</a>

            </div>
            <img src="thumbnail/Picture2.jpg" /> <a href="?delete=42" class="sbtn_red">Delete</a>  <a href="#" class="caption sbtn_gray">caption</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i got many answer in stackoverlflow and i tried many but not really work. may be i am missing something.

```
$(".caption").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.captionbox').slideToggle();
    });
```

in my demo have many js code which i commented. guys can check. 
http://jsfiddle.net/t2j162bv/1/ demo

Comment: Your id's are repeated - invalid code. In JSFiddle you do not load jQuery (left side menu from dropdown). Your `.caption` is link with only text content, there is no `.captionbox` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup, `captionbox` is the sibling of the `caption` so

```
$('.caption').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.captionbox').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks.. may i know now to close that when i click close.  i uploaded demo http://jsfiddle.net/t2j162bv/2/

Answer (score 0):

i made it finally. demo is  http://jsfiddle.net/t2j162bv/3/

```
$('.caption').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.captionbox').slideToggle();
});
$(".collapsed").click(function(){
     $(this).parent(".captionbox").slideUp('slow');
});
```

thanks @arun